# Tests for views in Django application

Tags: python, django, functional-testing

I have few models in my `models.py`. Two of them are as follows:

```
class Event():
      eventName = models.CharField( unique = True )

class Job():
      event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
      jobName = models.CharField

      class Meta:
          unique_together(('event','jobName'))
```

I was testing a modelform of this class, using `Client module` from `django.test`. The test where I am failing is while testing for `unique_together` property

Following is my `test.py`

```
class TestJobView(TestCase):
    def test_duplicate_job_in_same_event(self):
        Event.objects.create(eventName='test_event', noOfVolunteersRequired=10,
                startDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05', endDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05')

        Job.objects.create(event=Event.objects.get(eventName='test_event'),
                   jobName='test_jobName',jobDescription='test_jobDescription_1',
                   noOfVolunteersRequired=10, startDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05', 
                   endDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05')
        self.assertEqual(1, Job.objects.filter(event__eventName='test_event', 
                           jobName='test_jobName').count())

        c = Client()

        response = c.post('/AdminUnit/job/',{'event' : 'test_event',
        'jobName' : 'test_jobName','jobDescription' : 'test_jobDescription_2',
        'startDate' : '2014-05-05 05:05:05', 'endDate' : '2014-05-05 05:05:05', 
        'noOfVolunteersRequired' : 5})

        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
        print response.context['jobsForm']['event'].errors
```

The result of the above test prints `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`

Now, I have two questions. Firstly, this exception should not have been raised as an event is already created and is also `asserted True` in the above method. Secondly, If I try the same thing from my view, It raises a `non_field_error` and says `Job with this Event and JobName already exists.` . How do I capture this in my tests.py using response ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show your view or form, but presumably you are just using the default ModelForm which represents a ForeignKey as a ModelChoiceField. So, the value to post for `event` is not the name, but the ID, which you should capture when you create the Event at the start of the test.

I should add, however, that I don't think you should be testing this at all. Unit tests are for your code, not Django's. `unique_together` is a part of Django itself and as such is very well-covered by the Django's own unit tests. There is no need for you to replicate that functionality explicitly.

**Edit**

I don't understand your second comment. Your test should look like this:

```
def test_duplicate_job_in_same_event(self):
    event = Event.objects.create(...)
    job = Job.objects.create(event=event, ...)
    response = self.client.post('/AdminUnit/job/',{'event' : event.id, ...})
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct I'm simply using a `ModelForm` . Sorry I'm new to django and hence didn't got your ID part. Could you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: To add to that, `event` is the name and `id_event` is the ID of event field. I checked this by `print response`. I'm also using the same concept elsewhere and therefore sure about it being the name and not ID

Comment: Thanks, I got what you were meaning to say by id & name. Also, even If I write the test for this view  (regression test) this would raise a `non_field_error`. How can I access this in my `tests.py` . Ex we access field errors like `response.context['jobsForm']['event'].errors`

Comment: `response.context['jobsForm'].non_field_errors()` is what I was asking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Ad Daniel Roseman noticed, `unique_together` should not be tested here. If it should be tested at all is a mater of opinion. However, the `unique_together` is defined on model level, and luckily everything becomes much simpler when you unit-test it there:

```
class TestJob(TestCase):
    def test_duplicate_in_same_event(self):
        event = Event.objects.create(
            eventName='test_event', noOfVolunteersRequired=10,
            startDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05', endDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05')

        Job.objects.create(
            event=event,
            jobName='test_jobName',jobDescription='test_jobDescription_1',
            noOfVolunteersRequired=10, startDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05', 
            endDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05')

        job = Job(
            event=event,
            jobName='test_jobName',jobDescription='test_jobDescription_1',
            noOfVolunteersRequired=10, startDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05', 
            endDate='2014-05-05 05:05:05')

        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            job.validate_unique()
```